# Retrofit error code JSON

Tags: android, retrofit2

My API is return on success:

```
{"error_code": 0, "last_login": "2016-01-18T22:27:20.342Z", "facebook_id": "1", "id": 1, ..}
```

And on error:

```
{"error_code": 1}
```

My retrofit interface is returning User object. But in case of an error all the User fields is set to null. How can I get the error code? (without adding error_code field to User object)

Here is the function deceleration:

```
@GET("/login")
Call<User> login (@Query("facebook_id") String facebook_id);
```

And the call:

```
Call<User> call = apiService.login("2");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<User> response) {
            // Here I wan't to check somehow the error_code
            User user = response.body();
            Toast.makeText(context, "OK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: what response code is your api returning in case of error ?

Comment: Take a look on [these articles](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it with parent class which contains error_code field and all the API objects inherit from this parent.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class User {
    public int error_code;
    //other keys like last_login

    public boolean hasError (){
        return error_code == 0;
    }

}
```

In the `onResponse(..) {}` block, call:

```
if(response.body().hasError()) {
    Toast("Error:");
}
```

Comment: This will probably do the work (notice that I also write about it in the question), but I'm sure Retrofit has more generic way for error handling.